# Parsing values on Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm cleaning up a data base that centers around monetary donations.

The `donor_name` column consists of both `individual donors` and `organizations`.

`Organizations` have unique characters that `individual names` do not, like '`LLC`', '&', '`Inc`.', etc.

Is there a way to extract entries that have such characters and then put them in a new column?

Comment: Do you have a table dictionary for all words you're trying to find?

Comment: No. The words that i'm trying to find come from a single column of data.

Answer (score 0):

It may look ugly but you can use this :

```
SELECT individual_donors ,
(CASE WHEN organizations LIKE  '%LLC%' THEN organizations END) as LLC,
(CASE WHEN organizations LIKE  '%Inc%' THEN organizations END) as INC
FROM donor_name GROUP BY individual_donors, organizations ;
```